# How to convert the axes into log-scale with scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a pgfplot for my project report. But not able to transform the axis of my plot in log scales with scientific notation. Can someone show my mistake and help.

Output:

[image]

**code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=-2,xmax=10,
    ymin=1e-5,ymax=1,
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
    ylabel style={align=center, font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    xlabel style={align=center, font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    x tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    y tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    log ticks with fixed point,
    scatter/classes={%
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
    \addplot[scatter,only marks,%
        scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
    table[meta=label] {
x     y      label
0.1   0.15   a 
0.45  0.27   c 
0.02  0.17   a 
0.06  0.1    a 
0.9   0.5    b 
0.5   0.3    c 
0.85  0.52   b 
0.12  0.05   a 
0.73  0.45   b 
0.53  0.25   c 
0.76  0.5    b 
0.55  0.32   c
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
xmin=-2, xmax=10,
ymin=1e-2, ymax=1e0,
xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
scatter/classes={a={mark=square*, blue}, b={mark=triangle*, red}, c={mark=o, black}},
]
\addplot[scatter, only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic]
table[meta=label] {
x     y      label
0.1   0.15   a 
0.45  0.27   c 
0.02  0.17   a 
0.06  0.1    a 
0.9   0.5    b 
0.5   0.3    c 
0.85  0.52   b 
0.12  0.05   a 
0.73  0.45   b 
0.53  0.25   c 
0.76  0.5    b 
0.55  0.32   c
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Semi log graph with scatter points]

Comment: Perhaps: xmin=0, xmax=1.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I wanted to have both the axis in log scales. Currently only y-axis is in log scale. Solved : I used loglogaxis instead of semilogyaxis

Answer (score 2):

With the little change (`xmin=0, xmax=1`) to hpekristinasen answer the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had initially show xmin to be -2